# How to print multiple values through OOP without adding them in Java

Tags: java, oop

What I am wanting is to print out each of these methods out, not add their values together. I assume this is why I got an error trying to put boolean values in the first System.out statement. Do I have to give each one it's own System.out.println statement?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Block dirt = new Block(1, 100, 1, false, false, 0, 1, 100, 1)
    {

    };
    System.out.println(dirt.getSpawnLevel() + dirt.getSize() + dirt.getHardness() + dirt.getOpacity() + dirt.getRarity() + dirt.getBounceHeight() + dirt.getStackSize());

    System.out.println(dirt.getFlammable());
    System.out.println(dirt.getBlockBounce());

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Block dirt = new Block(1, 100, 1, false, false, 0, 1, 100, 1)
    {

    };
```

Change the previous code by:

```
Block dirt = new Block(1, 100, 1, false, false, 0, 1, 100, 1);
```

Also print the output like this:

```
System.out.println(dirt.getSpawnLevel()+"," + dirt.getSize()+"," + dirt.getHardness()+"," + dirt.getOpacity()+"," + dirt.getRarity()+"," + dirt.getBounceHeight()+"," + dirt.getStackSize());
```

Comment: That makes sense, but is there a way to display all of my values in a single println statement?

Comment: Yes, what you did should work, provided methods are not void.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. See, if I do one with a value of 100 & another with the value of 1, I get 101. I want it to be "100, 1, etc.." not 101

Comment: You can override toString() method inside Block class. Also if you want to append strings use StringBuilder. please dont use + operatior when performing string manipulations.

Comment: So simple, just did that exact thing yesterday too.. Jeez.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```
System.out.println("" + dirt.getSpawnLevel() + dirt.getSize() + dirt.getHardness() + dirt.getOpacity() + dirt.getRarity() + dirt.getBounceHeight() + dirt.getStackSize());
```

having a string in the left part of a + (here an empty one) will give a string as a result. So for example

```
"myString" + 3;
```

is a string containing myString3

and so

```
"myString" + 3 + 4;
```

will start creating a string myString3, then again, string + int is string so you will end with  myString34